# XLSXWriter: Using A1 notation on conditional formatting gives me the error "Arguments missing for parameters "last_row", "last_col""

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, xlsxwriter, pylance

I try to use the so-called A1 notation on the conditional_format method like this:

```
standard_worksheet.conditional_format(
    "A1:B98", {"type": "cell", "criteria": "==", "value": '"Hard"', "format": hard})
```

VS Code highlights this as seen here

[image: 1].

However, the last_row and last_col parameters should only be necessary when using Row/Column notation.

Is there an error on my side or are Python, VSCode, or the module doing something wrong?

Here are the docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html

What did you try and what were you expecting?

Well, not getting a Syntax highlighting.

Comment: This is a VS Code (or maybe more correctly a Pylance plugin) issue. The code is valid in Python and XlsxWriter. There is a decorator on that `conditional_format()` method, and most other XlsxWriter methods, to allow the syntactic sugar of named Excel ranges. Although, in fairness, that is reasonably hard information to parse.

Comment: Oh thanks, the code does actually work fine when I run it. I was just confused because on similar methods, it also accepted strings without highlighting anything. So something I should open an issue for on the Pylance GitHub page?

Comment: Yes, I think you can open a feature request in pylance to enable them to support the identification.